# Resolve/Reject Promis within external callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, promise

I am playing with ajax & iterated promises to create an abstracted version for a ajax call. The below code is working fine.

```
function ajax(url){
    var xhr = {
        rq : function (method, url){
            var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //only accept 
                client.open(method,url,true);
                client.send();
                client.onload = function (){
                    if(this.status == 200){
                        if(this.response == "1"){
                            reject(this.response);
                        }
                        else{
                            resolve(this.response);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        reject(this.statusText);
                    }
                };
            });
            return prom;
        }
    };
    return {
        'get' : function(){
            return xhr.rq('GET', url);
        }
    };
}
```

However I want to abstract the function on ajax.onload to be passed as callback and I was thinking about something like this:

```
function ajax(url, checker){
    var xhr = {
        rq : function (method, url){
            var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //only accept 
                client.open(method,url,true);
                client.send();
                client.onload = checker;
                };
            });
            return prom;
        }
    };
    return {
        'get' : function(){
            return xhr.rq('GET', url);
        }
    };
}

function chk1(){
    if(this.status == 200){
        if(this.response == "1"){
            reject(this.response);
        }
        else{
            resolve(this.response);
        }
    }
    else{
        reject(this.statusText);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the error that resolve and reject are unknown. I kind of know that the problem is just that within chk1 the promise is not known. I am unsure however, how to resolve it.

I want to be able to call it something like this:

```
Promise.all([ajax(u,chk1).get(),ajax(v,chk1).get()])
.then(callback.success)
.catch(callback.error);
```

Kind Regards

Comment: you might need to do like `client.onload = checker.bind(this,resolve,reject)` to be able to reference the resolve and reject callbacks of the promise within your checker callback..

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `resolve` and `reject` to the checker function so it can call them as needed.

```
function ajax(url, checker) {
    var xhr = {
        rq: function(method, url) {
            var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //only accept 
                client.open(method, url, true);
                client.send();
                client.onload = function() {
                    checker.call(this, resolve, reject);
                };

            });
            return prom;
        }
    };
    return {
        'get': function() {
            return xhr.rq('GET', url);
        }
    };
}

function chk1(resolve, reject) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        if (this.response == "1") {
            reject(this.response);
        } else {
            resolve(this.response);
        }
    } else {
        reject(this.statusText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I found that I had to change this to an argument too.

Comment: @Snake707 - I already fixed that issue so `this` is preserved.

Comment: @Snake707 - The solution you posted will not work as you have it because it will not call `checker()` at the right time (it will call it too early).  Also, if this solution solves your problem, you can click the green checkmark tot he left of the answer to indicate that to the community.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who still cares. jfriend00's answer is gold. My final solution looks like this (I had to change from using this to another paramter):

```
function ajax(url, checker){
    var xhr = {
        rq : function (method, url){
            var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                //only accept 
                client.open(method,url,true);
                client.send();
                client.onload = checker(resolve, reject, client);
                });
            return prom;
        }
    };
    return {
        'get' : function(){
            return xhr.rq('GET', url);
        }
    };
}

function chk1(resolve, reject, xhr){
    if(xhr.status == 200){
        if(xhr.response == "1"){
            reject(xhr.response);
        }
        else{
            resolve(xhr.response);
        }
    }
    else{
        reject(xhr.statusText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work.  `client.onload = checker(resolve, reject, client);` will call `checker()` immediately, not when the `onload` event occurs.

Comment: Thanks! I see that now.